# Metasploit Error "The procedure entry point _gmtime64_s could not br located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll"

Tags: dll, msvcrt, entry-point, metasploit

I have installed metasploit on my Windows XP SP3, but when I run it in the command line using `msfconsole` I get the following error.

> The procedure entry point _gmtime64_s could not br located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

Could anyone help me out with this problem, please?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

So a certain function that serves as the entry point of msvcrt.dll doesn't not exist.
That means that you have to reconfigure or reinstall msvcrt.dll.

For x86: http://www.dlldownloader.com/msvcrt-dll/download/5f238fcbc736e8eea7473811c9508a13/

For x64: http://www.dlldownloader.com/msvcrt-dll/download/b3c89c069ac8614d25ae2dbbd4bbc349/

Download msvcrt.dll from these websites(scan them with antivirus software before using them), save you original msvcrt.dll to a new location, replace the original msvcrt.dll file and restart your program to see if this works.

Edit: If you're using the newest version of metasploit, it's possible that it no longer supports XP, a really old platform.

Comment: I downloaded the library from the first link provided, and replaced it with the one in the system32 folder, but still the error exists.

Comment: If you're using the newest version of metasploit, it's possible that it no longer supports XP, a really old platform.